# Natural decay in the rate of Animation

Tags: dynamic, animation

I am trying to introduce a decay into the rate of animation of a graphics object by setting the AnimationRate in the Animator to a dynamic variable which is itself continually updated through a self-triggering dynamic until it reaches a threshold value. While this variable behaves as expected, the animator does not: as you can see by the behavior of the animator's slider, it jumps all over the place and does not exhibit the gradual slowdown in the rate of scrolling that I was expecting.

```
Dynamic[spinspeed = Max[0.5, spinspeed - 0.005]]
Slider[Dynamic[spinspeed], {0, 6}]
Animator[u, {0, \[Pi]}, AnimationRate -> Dynamic[spinspeed]]
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired smooth autodecay?